# angular directive controller "this" returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, angular-directive

I'm trying to hook up two directives using `require` and sharing the parent controller.

I've done this a gazillion times in other projects, but for the life of me I can't get this to work...

The directive controller `this` is returning undefined, which in return makes it difficult to pass methods to the child directive...

here's my code for the parent directive:

```
app.directive('defaultHeader', () => {

    let defaultHeaderCtrl = ($scope, $element) => {

        let containEl,
            elHeight = 500;

        console.log(this) // returns 'undefined'

        function resizeElement(el, height) {
            el[0].style.height = `${height}px`
        }

        if (_.isUndefined($scope.coverImgUrl)) {
            resizeElement($element, elHeight);
        } else {

        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            coverImgUrl: '='
        },
        controller: defaultHeaderCtrl
    };
});
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoctrl/HB7LU/20750/) shows that the directive controller `this` should be returning the constructor.

Here's some context if anyone's intersted:

- ui router template is a directive element `<div default-header data="data"></div>`
- ui router resolves data, then passes it through the controller to the directive

thanks for the help

Comment: restrict 'A' in directive code but in your template you're using the directive as an element.

Comment: thanks @FidanHakaj - this was just example code, but I fixed it to better represent the the actual directive

Comment: I opened your fiddle and it is logging `Constructor {}`, not undefined

Comment: @MarioLamacchia - exactly - the fiddle shows that it should be returning the constructor, whereas my directive in my project wasn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrow functions (besides the fact they look neat) serve to replace [lexical `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) with contextual. Since the controller is defined within arrow function also, it will get its parent context as `this`. Which is `undefined` in strict mode.

Use

```
function defaultHeaderCtrl ($scope, $element) { ... }
```

and don't replace all `function` with arrows just because ES6 allows this.

Comment: Absolutely right: "don't replace all `function` with arrows just because ES6 allows this"

Comment: perfect answer - changed my answer to point to yours - I vaguely remember reading about the lexical `this` when diving into the babel compiler - I guess I need to revisit that :)

Comment: Yes, that's quite elegant replacement for old `var self = this` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be pretty simple to solve after I started looking at the differences between my code and the jsFiddle I posted.

I'm using babeljs, and evidently there's something going on with the scope when I use the arrow function syntax for the controller `() => {}`.

After switching that back to `function() {}`, `this` now returns the constructor, and the directives work as expected.

## See marked answer above for context ^